# Firebase Cloud Function returning empty collection

Tags: javascript, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to fetch all documents of a collection using cloud functions from a swift app. I see documents being returned from firebase console but in my swift app, I always get an empty result. I've tried the two variations of the function.

```
export const fetchCollection = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {
        if (!context.auth) return { status: 'error', code: 401, message: 'Not signed in' }
        const snapshot  = await firestore.collection(`/${data.collectionName}`).get()
        const collection = new Map()
        snapshot.forEach (doc => {
            collection.set(doc.id, doc.data())
        })
        return collection
    } catch (error) {
        return new functions.https.HttpsError(error.code, error.message)
    }
})
```

```
export const fetchCollection    = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if (!context.auth) return { status: 'error', code: 401, message: 'Not signed in' }
    return new Promise (async (resolve, reject) => {
        const snapshot = await firestore.collection(`/${data.collectionName}`).get()
        if (snapshot.empty) {
            reject({ "Error": "Did not find any thing" })
        } else {
            const collectionDocuments = new Map()
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                collectionDocuments.set(doc.id, doc.data())
            })
            resolve(collectionDocuments)
        }
    })
})
```

Here's my swift code

```
functions.httpsCallable("fetchCollection").call(request) { result, error in
            if error == nil {
                print("\(Date()) Result: \(result?.data as? [String: Any])")
            }
        }
```

Result is Always [:] and is nil if I use snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()) in cloud function.

Also, the timestamps in xCode are different than the logs in firebase console.

What am I doing wrong. Thanks for your help.